# Confusion of setInterval with setTimeout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to use setInterval with setTimeout in JavaScript.

```js
var temArr = []

let timer = setInterval(() => {
  var target = Math.random()
  temArr.push(target)
  console.log(6, target, temArr[temArr.length - 1], target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]) // one

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(9, target, temArr[temArr.length - 1], target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]) // two
  }, 500);
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer)
}, 10000);
```

<del>I expected that the last value of one and two would be true.</del>

I expected that every time when the logger print, both one and two have the same value of the third parameter, that means `target equals temArr[temArr.length - 1]`

<del>But the result is that one is true, and two is false</del>

But the intermediate result of two is false, and the last value is true, while one is alway true

When I switch the timeout value, <del>and the result is true</del> that means set the interval with value `500` and the timeout with value `100`, at this time both `target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]` is alway true every time the logger print

could you please tell me why?

Comment: The last line in the console for me is `9 0.357113447138378 0.357113447138378 true` so two is true as you expected.

Comment: I am so sorry, I didn't express the problem well, and I am already update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both returned true for me, just different order:

Ok `setInterval` VS `setTimeout`:

`setInterval` - will run the function inside EVERY `x` ms. which means:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('I will run every 100ms')
}, 100)
```

Will run EVERY 100ms.

`setTimeout` - will run the function inside AFTER `x` ms. which means:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('I will run after 10 seconds')
}, 10000);
```

will run AFTER 10 seconds.

---

So doing this:

```
let timer = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('I will run every 500ms';   

  setTimeout(() => {
    cosole.log('I will run AFTER 500ms EVERY 500ms');
  }, 500);
}, 100)
```

The log inside `setTimeout` will run 500ms AFTER the first log has been triggered and will trigger every 100ms.

---

**EDIT - Answer to user's edited question:**

For clearer logs, I modified your code:

```js
var temArr = []
var intervalOrder = 0;
var timeoutOrder = 0;

var timer = setInterval(() => {
  var target = Math.random()
  temArr.push(target)
   intervalOrder++

  console.log('ONE - SET TIMEOUT: ', {order: intervalOrder, target, tem: temArr[temArr.length - 1], result: target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]})

  setTimeout(() => {
timeoutOrder++
    console.log('TWO - SET TIMEOUT: ', {order: timeoutOrder, target, tem: temArr[temArr.length - 1], result: target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]}) // two
  }, 500);
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer)
}, 1000);
```

Notice how `TWO - SET TIMEOUT` doesn't fetch the same result as `ONE - SET TIMEOUT`? It's because it doesn't fetch the value of that variable when it was called but it fetches ON TRIGGER which means that the value already changed because `setInterval` has shorter time.

What you can do for this is to call the `setTiemout` on a different function so it will reference its value on the parameter instead of the newly generated one.

```js
var temArr = []
var intervalOrder = 0;
var timeoutOrder = 0;

var logSecond = (target) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
timeoutOrder++
    console.log('TWO - SET TIMEOUT: ', {order: timeoutOrder, target, tem: temArr[temArr.length - 1], result: target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]}) // two
  }, 500);
}

var timer = setInterval(() => {
  var target = Math.random()
  temArr.push(target)
   intervalOrder++

  console.log('ONE - SET TIMEOUT: ', {order: intervalOrder, target, tem: temArr[temArr.length - 1], result: target === temArr[temArr.length - 1]})
logSecond(target)
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timer)
}, 1000);
```

^^ on the snippet above, the target and result are now the same for both logs.

Comment: Yeah, thank you :) . Now I know the difference between setInterval and setTimeout

(I am so sorry, I didn't express the problem well, could you please help me again ? )

Comment: @Huanfeng.Xu I edited my answer for your edited question - kindly check the answer above (and accept if this is correct)